# How to convert an array into a set in CPLEX?

Tags: arrays, set, cplex, opl, ilog

Let's say that

```
int A=[1 2 3 4];
```

How to convert it into a Set?

```
{int} SetA =?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 range r=1..4;
int A[r]=[1, 2 ,3 ,4];

{int} s={A[i] | i in r};

execute
{
  writeln(s);
}
```

gives

```
{1 2 3 4}
```